# How to Implement Square payment method by using ASP .Net web api

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

How to implement the Square payment method by using an ASP.NET web API Actually, I am trying to implement the Square payment method in the asp.net core web API, but I got an error. This is the Controller Part of the Square Package in Visual Studio. 
Error show CreateAsync method
`CreatePaymentRequest` does not contain a definition for `CreateAsync` and no accessible extension method `CreateAsync` accepting a first argument of type `CreatePaymentRequest`
This is Controller Part

```
public class SquareController : Controller
    {
        
        private readonly ISquareServices _services;
        public SquareController(ISquareServices squareServices)
        {
            _services = squareServices;
        }
        [HttpPost("customer/add")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> AddSquearCustomer([FromBody] AddDetails addDetails, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            var result = await _services.CreatePaymentAsync(addDetails, cancellationToken);

            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK, result);
           

        }
    }
```

// This is repository part

```
public class SquareServices : ISquareServices
    {
        private readonly CreatePaymentRequest _createPaymentRequest;
        public SquareServices(CreatePaymentRequest createPaymentRequest)
        {
            _createPaymentRequest = createPaymentRequest;
        }
        public async Task<CreatePaymentResponse> CreatePaymentAsync(AddDetails addDetails, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {



            var response = await _createPaymentRequest.CreateAsync(addDetails, cancellationToken);
            return (response);
        }
    }
```

//Error show CreateAsync method
'CreatePaymentRequest' does not contain a definition for 'CreateAsync' and no accessible extension method 'CreateAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'CreatePaymentRequest'

```
var response = await _createPaymentRequest.CreateAsync(addDetails, cancellationToken);
```

//This is IRepository Part

```
public interface ISquareServices
    {
        Task<CreatePaymentResponse> CreatePaymentAsync(AddDetails addDetails, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));
    }
```

Comment: Why would you say "I got an error" and not actually post the error?

Comment: Could you please share your stacktrace or error details? What are the details of `_createPaymentRequest.CreateAsync`

Comment: 'CreatePaymentRequest' does not contain a definition for 'CreateAsync' and no accessible extension method 'CreateAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'CreatePaymentRequest' this is a error

Comment: Then where and whats your error details?